# Handle double quote while exporting dataframe to CSV

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a dataframe which contains double quote (") and comma in value. I am trying to export the dataframe into csv but unfortunately double quote is not displayed properly in exported csv.

I managed to handle all other special characters by setting "quoteAll" to true.

In csv, if you replace the single double quote with two double quotes, it works fine. But when I export to csv with below code, it replaces " with " in exported csv.

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace
val df = Seq((1, "A,B,C,\"DEF\""), (2, "DEF")).toDF("ID", "Val")

val updatedDf = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((acc, colname) => acc.withColumn(colname,regexp_replace(acc(s"`$colname`"), "\"", "\"\"")))


deltaDS.coalesce(1).write
.option("header", true)
.option("encoding", "utf-8")
.option("quoteAll", true)
.mode("Overwrite").csv("[Location to store csv]")
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

How can I handle this ?

Comment: Maybe the `charToEscapeQuoteEscaping` from the [Spark - CSV Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html) can help ? Please do have a look at `escape` and `escapeQuotes` as well since they seem to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided exact plaintext csv you expect, so it's hard to guess. Are you looking for this?

```
val df = Seq((1, "A,B,C,\"DEF\""), (2, "DEF")).toDF("ID", "Val")

df.coalesce(1).write
.option("header", true)
.option("encoding", "utf-8")
.option("quoteAll", true)
.option("escape", "\"")  // escapes quotes inside quote using "
.mode("Overwrite").csv("xxx")
```

Resulting csv:

```
"ID","Val"
"1","A,B,C,""DEF"""
"2","DEF"
```

Comment: That worked. I was missing `.option("escape", "\"")` Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input, the following seems to be the dataframe outputs.

**df:**

[image: df]

**updatedDF:**

[image: updatedDF]

Since quoteAll is set to true, it will work as mentioned in the spark documentation.

[image]

When converted to CSV, following seems to be the output.

**df.csv:**

```
"ID","Val"
"1","A,B,C,\"DEF\""
"2","DEF"
```

**updatedDF.csv:**

```
"ID","Val"
"1","A,B,C,\"\"DEF\"\""
"2","DEF"
```

One suggestion to deal with the escape character is to use the original dataframe and make the escape character as empty. **But please be wary of the impact it might have on the other special characters.**

```scala
%scala
df.coalesce(1).write
.option("header", true)
.option("encoding", "utf-8")
.option("quoteAll", true)
.option("escape", "")
.mode("Overwrite").csv("<path>/tst_1dq_noesc.csv")
```

```
"ID","Val"
"1","A,B,C,"DEF""
"2","DEF"
```

Hope this is the expected output...

Comment: Cant empty escape. I have new line characters as well. \n \r etc...