# Spark - CSV - Write Options - Quotes

Tags: csv, apache-spark, databricks, spark-csv

Hope everyone is doing well.

While going through the [spark csv datasource options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html) for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398490/handle-double-quote-while-exporting-dataframe-to-csv/74428501#74428501) I am quite confused on the difference between the various quote related options available.

[image: spark-csv-quote-options]

1. Do we have any detailed differences between them ?
2. Does any option override the other or they all work together ?

Used the example mentioned in the linked question to understand the differences, but still a little confused. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's run through a few examples.

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "aaa"),
  (2, "b,c"),
  (3, "d$e"),
  (4, "f%g")
).toDF("x", "y")
df.show

+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|  1|aaa|
|  2|b,c|
|  3|d$e|
|  4|f%g|
+---+---+
```

Whenever you have commas in values that would be indistinguishable from field delimiters (like `2,b,c`) Spark can quote such values. It's double quotes by default (like `2,"b,c"`), but you can customize it using **quote** option.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("quote", "$")
  .csv("x")

1,aaa
2,$b,c$
3,$d\$e$
4,f%g
```

We used dollar sign here. Not only `b,c` was quoted, but since `d$e` contained a dollar, it was quoted as well and the dollar itself was escaped.

I don't know why you would like to do that, but you can ask Spark not to escape fields containing quote character using **escapeQuotes** option.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("quote", "$")
  .option("escapeQuotes", false)
  .csv("x")

1,aaa
2,$b,c$
3,d$e
4,f%g
```

Here, `d$e` remained unquoted.

You can also force it to quote every field using **quoteAll**.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("quote", "$")
  .option("quoteAll", true)
  .csv("x1")

$1$,$aaa$
$2$,$b,c$
$3$,$d\$e$
$4$,$f%g$
```

Note that *quoteAll = true* makes *escapeQuotes* irrelevant.

You can customize the escape character for the quote character inside quote using **escape**, if you don't like the default backslash.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("quote", "$")
  .option("escape", "%")
  .csv("x1")

1,aaa
2,$b,c$
3,$d%$e$
4,$f%g$
```

Finally, note that there's a standalone escape character in `f%g`, so if you would like to escape that, use **charToEscapeQuoteEscaping**.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("quote", "$")
  .option("escape", "%")
  .option("quoteAll", true)
  .option("charToEscapeQuoteEscaping", "^")
  .csv("x1")

$1$,$aaa$
$2$,$b,c$
$3$,$d%$e$
$4$,$f^%g$
```

No, you can't go deeper and escape `^`...

Comment: extra ordinary explanation...

Comment: Is below summary accurate ? `quote` - enclose string that contains the delimiter i.e. comma in a csv
`escape` - when the quote character is part of string, it is escaped with escape character
`escapeQuote` - when the quote character is part of string, it is escaped with escape character, escapeQuote is used to ignore it.
`quoteAll` - quote all the fields irrespective of whether they contain a delimiter or other special characters.
`charToEscapeQuoteEscaping` - when the escape character is part of string, it is escaped with charToEscapeQuoteEscaping

quoteAll = true overrides escapeQuotes

Comment: Also does quote work just on delimiter or even on other special characters such as \r, \n, \000, \001 etc ?

Comment: Yes, that's quite accurate. A value containing \n is quoted, because that's a record delimiter. Anything else than quote character, record and field delimiter is not.